# Create a custom response from laravel using fetch API

Tags: laravel, reactjs, fetch

I am currently making a `POST` request to my laravel API using the following code...

```
fetch('http://laravel.dev/content', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode:'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({

        })
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

The route looks as follows...

```
Route::post('/content', array('middleware' => 'cors', 'uses' => 'Test@save'));
```

Although I have configured `cors` mode, I am actually using `no-cors`.

My controller `Test@save` looks like...

```
class Test extends Controller
{

    public function save() 
    {
       echo "here";
    }
}
```

I am trying to send the string `here` back to the fetch request. But in my fetch request, when I do `console.log(response)`, I get the following response...

```
Response {type: "opaque", url: "", status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "" ...}
```

Is there any way to send a custom response using my Laravel route? If so, how do I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as:

```
public function save() 
{
    return response()->json(['data' => 'here']);
}
```

> The json method will automatically set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, as well as convert the given array into JSON using the json_encode PHP function.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#json-responses)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You must return another promise, that gets text or json from fetch:

```
fetch('http://laravel.dev/content', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({

    })
})
.then((response) => response.text()) //or response.json()
.then((text) => {
    console.log(text);
});
```

Also, you need to make a cors request, otherwise you can't access the response. You'll need to add this global middleware to laravel if you want to accept ajax requests from all origins

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type');
    }
}
```

Read [This article](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#global-middleware) on global middleware.

Comment: I set up this exact middle ware, but I still get the error message `Fetch API cannot load http://laravel.dev/content. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: You have to add it to your list of middleware inside of app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: I did. But I still get an error and I can't figure out why. I can make a repo on github if that helps, as I feel like I've tried everything to get it to work.

Comment: Well what is the error now? I have built many react apps powered by a laravel backend. I'd love to help.

Comment: this is the error message currently `Fetch API cannot load http://laravel.dev/content. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access 
control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: also, ive posted another question regarding CORS here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617875/laravel-api-cors-mode-not-working ... Ive tried to configure CORS but I can't get it to work still

Comment: You may need to add it to your global middleware, not route specific middleware.

Comment: Im pretty sure I tried that too, Im pretty close to giving up lol :(