# Laravel API CORS mode not working

Tags: laravel, reactjs, cors, fetch

I did a lot of research and I implemented the following middleware to get around the CORS error I keep getting...

Middleware/Cors.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class Cors
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type');
    }
}

?>
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'cors' => App\Http\Middleware\Cors,
];
```

Routes.php

```
Route::post('/content', array('middleware' => 'cors', 'uses' => 'Test@save'));
```

This seems to be configured properly. But when I make the request using fetch API...

```
fetch('http://laravel.dev/content', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({

        })
    })
    //.then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => response.text()) 
    .then((text) => {
        console.log(text);
    });
```

I still get this error...

```
Fetch API cannot load http://laravel.dev/content. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access 
control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried adding `no-cors` mode to my fetch response, and it worked, I got an opaque response, but I need cors mode to get a proper request.

It might be worthwhile to note that my `App` and my Laravel `restAPI` are located in the same `htdocs` folder on `XAMPP`. I'm not sure if this is an issue.

I also tried adding the headers at the top of my Routers.php file but I still get the same error. Can I even configure a restAPI using laravel?

Comment: For cors you can try this GitHub [repo(https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)]. It's very easy to use and works in my projects.

Comment: This header shouldn't exist in the request headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Agree with the above. Also for me it had to be part of the global middleware group

Comment: @Amit the link gives me 404 not found

Comment: try the credentials option, `credentials: 'same-origin'` or  `credentials: 'include'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove

```
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type');
```

in **class Cors** like this

```
<?php
   namespace App\Http\Middleware;
   use Closure;

   class Cors
   {
        /**
        * Handle an incoming request.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @param  \Closure  $next
        * @return mixed
        */
       public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
          return $next($request)
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
           ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS');

       }
  }

 ?>
```

It worked for me.I hope it helpfull for you