# Keep getting error with `Fetch` `response.json()`

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a JavaScript widget with the code:

```
function submit(email, pass){
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/example', {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Origin": "*",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        },
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: pass
        })
    })
    .then(

        response => response.json(),///<---always give error

        error => console.log('An error occurred.', error)
    )
    .then(
        res => dispatch(completeTransactionsSave(res)
    )
    })
}
```

I keep getting error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

The line `response.json()` causes the error. I checked many tutorials and all seems to be using the same code and get back the result.

How can I resolve this?

**Important Note**
I just found out that happened because I am testing it with localhost. The moment I deploy it to real server, everything works fine.
The lesson, never test cross origin stuff with localhost.

Comment: @JaromandaX for testing purposes, my server side i just return simple statement: `return ['status'=>'login success'];`. I get it back from `Postman` no problem:`{"status":"widget login success"}`. is there other way i need to format this?

Comment: found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616588/create-a-custom-response-from-laravel-using-fetch-api. the accepted answer could be the solution

Comment: @JaromandaX in network/response tab: `failed to load response data`. Let me try that accepted answer above and see if it works.

Comment: Make sure that the response type coming back actually is application/json. If it’s anything else such as an error HTML page you may need to use text() instead. You can see by reviewing the Content-Type in the response headers visible in developer tools.

Comment: Wrong lesson. I test cross origin stuff with localhost all the time. You need to get your localhost server code to send the correct headers.